# Nest Wordpress Loop With Multiple Meta Keys & Values

Tags: wordpress, loops, nested

> So, I'm working on a social political website. Currently I'm working on the map page that contains all 100 North Carolina Counties and when you hover each county, it's corresponding election results / data displays. For the first loop, I'm pulling out the election result numbers and percentages to each party ( Republican, Democratic, Other ). To display the corresponding candidate to each election results, I've had to create a nested loop. I've decided to throw the nested loop into a function so it's not sitting in with the rest of the code on the template. This is what it looks like in my functions.php file:

```
function grabcandidatename($county, $office, $party) {

$args = array(array('key' => 'county', 'value' => $county),array('key' => 'office', 'value' => $office),array('key' => 'party', 'value' => $party) );
$c_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'government_officials',
    'show_posts' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $args
    )
));
if($c_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ($c_query->have_posts()) : $c_query->the_post(); 
        echo the_title();
    endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
}
```

> Alright, now - this is what it looks like in my template file for this bit:

```
//This pulls information from the election results that each candidate custom post type can relate to.
$category = get_the_category();
$officer = get_field('office');
```

> This is the function being called out. Remember, it's being called out in the election result's loop.

```
grabcandidatename($category,$officer,'republican');
```

> Now, the result that I am getting from all of this: I am getting the candidate name, but instead of getting the candidate name for the corresponding election result, I'm getting all of the candidate names together listed with each election result. So, my thought would be that my meta keys & values are being ignored. I understand that right now I have them stuffed in my $args variable, but that was just to tidy things up. If I list the arrays with the 'meta_query' then my candidate names don't even show up on my election results page.
>
> Thanks in advance!

Alright, I've fixed it.

Alright, so the code above works. I was just an idiot and forgot to enter in meta data options in for county and office. But, to keep me from having to re-enter all 100 counties, I've just tied in the taxonomy used to election results, into candidates as well. So, the code goes as follows.

To share a taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('the_county', array('election_results','government_officials'), $args);
```

To create a nested loop inside a function:

```
function grabcandidatename($county, $office, $party) {
$c_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'government_officials',
    'show_posts' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => 'the_county',
    'term' => $county,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'office',
            'value' => $office
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'party',
            'value' => $party
        ),
    )
));
if($c_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ($c_query->have_posts()) : $c_query->the_post(); 
        echo the_title();
    endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
}
```

Then, call the function containing the nested loop inside of another loop on your page template:

```
grabcandidatename($termname,$officer,'republican');
```

Comment: Just a quick observation - single quotes around a variable name won't insert the variable - drop the quotes or use double quotes. `'value' => '$county'`

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the helpful hint! I'll apply it to the top post as soon as I make the edit to my file.